# Trigger default scroll behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mouseevent, jquery-events

I need to trigger the default scroll behavior, like what happens with the scroll wheel.

However, I shouldn't just do
`$("body").scrollTop($("body").scrollTop() - 10)` because I don't know that the window would scroll down by only 10 pixels. For some computers, it may be 20 pixels, for others, it may be 50.

I really just want to trigger the built-in default behavior, so I don't have to worry about this.

(In case you're wondering, this is because I'm trying to make it so if you scroll inside an iframe, the parent window scrolls instead. I've managed to get the child window to have the parent window's function called, now I just need to trigger a similar scroll wheel event that happened in the iframe)

Ideas?

Comment: Let the scroll happen once (not prevented) on the outer framing page, examine how much it it offset the page, and remember that value?

Comment: indeed, that's my backup plan. i'd really like to be able to do this more cleanly though.